# How to select the last n % elements of an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, element

I have a sorted array and I would like to keep only the last 50-60-70% (generally n%) of the elements. How can I achieve this?

For example

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].last(this.size*0.7)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Modifying it slightly to be more generic, `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; a.last(a.size*0.7)` does return elements 4 through 9 as an array. Is that not what you want?

Comment: You could also define a new method for the class `Array`: `class Array; def last_percent(p); self.last(self.size * 0.01 * p); end; end`. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].last_percent(35) => [7, 8, 9]`. Adding a method to a built-in Ruby class is called "monkey-patching`. Some embrace the practice; others loathe it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `tap` in order to reference the object like you want.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].tap { |this| break this.last(this.size*0.7) }
```

The `break` is needed because tap normally ignores the block's return value.

Answer (score 1):

*I don't know Ruby, but I can google and guess.*

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a[a.size * 0.6..-1] ==> [6, 7, 8, 9]
a.last(a.size * 0.4) ==> [7, 8, 9]
```

The reason for this is that you first have to give the array a name, before you can reference it. In this case, `a`.

You can look up the functionality like this in the relevant documentation: [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html).

Comment: Thx, but I wanted to avoid the introducing of a new variable.

Comment: @Konstantin: Okay. Just state this in your question the next time. ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the functionality you are requesting you could use `#tap` which allows you to alter the method chain inside a block like this

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].tap do |a| 
    #a is the original array passed into a block
    a.delete_if.with_index{|index,element| element if index + 1 < a.size * 0.7}
 end
 #=> [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Please note this is destructive to the original array because you are tapping into it which does not seem like a concern since you are not storing the original array in a variable right now anyway.

Not sure why you would not want to store the array in a variable though as it makes the procedure far easier. A simple method like would suffice for this

```
def last_n_percent(array,percent=0.5)
  array.last(array.size * percent)
end
```